# Autoupdate maxdate setting daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I have two input date using **daterangepicker**, `input one` and `input two`. I want to know how to make `maxDate` on `input two` after user choose the date on `input one`. I have success add `endDate` setting on `input two`, but I need `maxDate` setting for prevent user choose over the date they choose on `input one`

Here's the html code

```
 <input type="text" name="input_one" id="input_one" />
 <input type="text" name="input_two" id="input_two" />
```

Here's js code

```
 $('input[name="input_one"]').daterangepicker({
    minDate:moment(),
    timePicker: false,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    autoApply: true,
    autoUpdateInput: true,
    locale: {
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    }
 }, function(start, end, label){
   var selectedEndDate = end.format('DD-MM-YYYY');

   $checkinInput = $('#input_one');

   var checkInPicker = $checkinInput.data('daterangepicker');

   checkInPicker.setEndDate(selectedEndDate);
 })

 $('input[name="input_two"]').daterangepicker({
    minDate:moment(),
    timePicker: false,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    autoApply: true,
    autoUpdateInput: true,
    locale: {
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    }
 })
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solutions, so before `input two` daterangepicker functions, add `onchange` function based on `input one` clicked.

Here's the code

```
$('#input_one').on('change', function(){
    $('#input_two').daterangepicker({
        maxDate:moment($('#input_one').val(), "DD-MM-YYYY"),
        minDate:moment(),
        timePicker: false,
        singleDatePicker: true,
        autoApply: true,
        autoUpdateInput: true,
        locale: {
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
        }
    })
});
```